# React Flow Chart: Input Text not working properly inside chart nodes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-chartjs

I have been using npm package `react-flow-chart` for creating flow chart.

Now, I have added a text input component inside every node,

but, when I type, the onChange event of my component is not triggering !!

Is there any property of chart that affects text inputs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the reason after enough research...
When typing inside an input text, which is in a chart node
the chart node re-renders each time,
which makes input text to re-render

The only way to type in the input box, is to set "readonly" property of chart "true" when typing, this will stop the re-rendering of chart nodes !!